# What happens when you click a button using WebRat under cucumber

Tags: cucumber, webrat

I am trying to login to a Java web application.

The login page has the following html :

```
  <html>
    <head><title>Login Page</title></head>
    <body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
      <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
      <form name='f' action='/ui/j_spring_security_check' method='POST'>
       <table>
          <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='j_password'/></td></tr>
          <tr>
             <td><input type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me'/> </td>
             <td>Remember me on this computer.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"/></td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset"/></td></tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I use the following script:

```
Given  /^I am logged in as (.*) with password (.*)$/ do | user, password |
  visit "http://localhost:8080/ui"
  click_link "Projects"
  puts "Response Body:"
  puts response.body
  assert_contain "User:"
  fill_in "j_username", :with => user
  fill_in "j_password", :with => password
  puts "Response Body:"
  puts response.body
  click_button
  puts "Response Body:"
  puts response.body
end
```

This gives the following in the log file :

```
[INFO] Response Body:
[INFO] <html><head><title>Login Page</title></head><body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
[INFO] <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3><form name='f' action='/ui/j_spring_security_check' method='POST'>
[INFO]  <table>
[INFO]     <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''></td></tr>
[INFO]     <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='j_password'/></td></tr>
[INFO]     <tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me'/></td><td>Remember me on this computer.</td></tr>
[INFO]     <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"/></td></tr>
[INFO]     <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset"/></td></tr>
[INFO]   </table>
[INFO] </form></body></html>
[INFO] Response Body:
[INFO] <html><head><title>Login Page</title></head><body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
[INFO] <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3><form name='f' action='/ui/j_spring_security_check' method='POST'>
[INFO]  <table>
[INFO]     <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''></td></tr>
[INFO]     <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='j_password'/></td></tr>
[INFO]     <tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me'/></td><td>Remember me on this computer.</td></tr>
[INFO]     <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"/></td></tr>
[INFO]     <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset"/></td></tr>
[INFO]   </table>
[INFO] </form></body></html>
[INFO] Response Body:
[INFO] 
[INFO]     Given I am logged in as pti with password ptipti # features/step_definitions/authentication_tests.rb:2
```

So apparently the response.body disappeared after clicking the submit button. I can see from the server log files that the script does not arrive on the Project page.

I am new to webrat and quite new to ruby and I am now thoroughly confused. I have no idea why the response.body is gone. I have no idea where I am.

I speculated that I had to wait for the page request, but all documentation says that webrat nicely waits till all redirects, pageloads, etc are finished. (At least I think I read that).  Besides I find no method to wait for the page in the webrat API.

Can someone give some tips on how to proceed with debugging this?

Comment: Seems that you have both a "submit" and a "reset" button on the form. Maybe Webrat is confused as to which button to push?

Comment: yeah,... but that would only reset the value of the fields to the original values... I am stumped.... I'll let the weekend do its work and revisit it monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed the behaviour using native ruby to exclude any jruby or JVM related issues.

I reconfigured webrat to use Selenium so I could see what was happening.

What happened was that after login there is a 302 redirect. The selenium implementation is following the redirect, but the mechanize implementation does not. So I was interpreting the body of the redirect message which is of course empty.

So I faked the redirect by exlipcitely visit-ing the page where I expect to be redirect and lo-and-behold : it works!.